# At runtime, how to specify a class so that a function can create an object of that specific class?

Tags: java

I have an interface called Model. It has a method called deserialize()

```
public interface Model 
{
   public void deserialize(String s);
}
```

There are many implementations of the Model interface.

I have a special class called Utilities that works on Model objects (i.e. implementations of the Model interface).

In Utilities, I have a function that takes a specified class, an creates a list of objects of that class.

```
 public static <T extends Model> List<T> getList(StringReader reader, Class <T> theClass)
{
   ...
}
```

I have two classes A and B that both implement Model. In class A, I have the following code -

```
A
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
  ArrayList<B> listOfBObjects;


public void deserialize(String dataString)
 {
    ...
    ...
    listOfBObjects = Utilities.getList();  <-- here I want to specify "B". How to do that?
 }
}
```

How to specify "B" as an argument to the getList() function above?

Comment: Factory objects are the traditional way to deal with stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listOfBObjects = Utilities.getList(new StringReader(dataString), B.class);
```

But I answered this in your previous question...

Comment: Ya, but maybe not before I posted this here!

Comment: Then you are one helluva fast question poster :) Checked, I answered 11 mins ago, and this question is from 5 mins ago. But I guess you were busy writing the question.